# Spring-data-mongodb transform and order by a field

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am new to using mongodb in springboot.

In relational databases we can transform the field (from say String to date) and sort on that transformed value.

e.g.

> SELECT * FROM `car` order by str_to_date(printDate, '%m-%d-%Y') DESC;
>
> [ {"name": "abc", "printDate": "06-21-2018"},  {"name": "def",
>   "printDate": "07-04-2017"} ]

I am trying to use Mongodb instead of mysql.

I created a PagingAndSortingRepository, But I am not able to pass a function in the orderField.

> Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(
>                   0,
>                   100
>                   , Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "$dateFromString('printDate')")
>           );
>
> `return carSampleRepository.query(pageable);`

Is there a way to do that in SpringBoot Spring-data-mongodb ?

Thank you

Comment: You'd need to give us some sample data in order to get a proper answer. But this link should help: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/

Comment: The sample data (JSON) is provided above.